# SSL Certificates on a Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm new to Tomcat but have been thrown in at the deep-end and asked to set up a new SSL Cert on a tomcat hosted site.

So, after much research, i did the following:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore server.keystore

keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -file server.csr -keystore server.keystore
```

I took the server.csr content and created a new signed certificate with Comodo.  Once created, i was emailed a link to a .cer file which I downloaded.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mykey -file file_i_got.cer -keystore server.keystore
```

On doing this, I get `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` in Chrome from an external connection.  When connecting from the domain it's on I inspect the cert and it shows that there is a Cert and that isn't self signed (obviously, not what i wanted).

I did configure Tomcat's server.xml and changed:

```
keystoreFile="conf/keystore"
```

to

```
keystoreFile="conf/server.keystore"
```

Is there further configuration I am missing?  For example, I couldn't find a reference to the alias, which seems like it should be needed.  But i have read and understand the first valid key will be used.  Since there is only one, I was hoping this would work.

Any help would be welcome, Thank you!

Comment: which tomcat version? how is the https connector configured (`server.xml`). From the chrome error message, could be you can't negociate a tls protocol between the browser and tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the import again without the `trustcacerts`. This is your certificate, not a CA's. Use the same alias you used when generating the key pair and CSR.